# C++ Struct invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am getting errors about Invalid use of non-static members as well as other issues from the struct members not working properly, I am having trouble understanding what the problem is, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


struct classroom {
int RoomNumber;
int NumberOfChairs;
int NumberOfStudents;
int ListOfStudents[NumberOfStudents];
string LectureName;
bool Window, Projector, Available;
}classroom;




int main() {

cout << "Please enter your room number" << endl;
cin >> classroom.RoomNumber;
cout << "Enter the name of the Lecture" << endl;
cin >> classroom.LectureName;
cout << "Enter  number of students" << endl;
cin >> classroom.NumberOfStudents;
cout << "Enter " << classroom.NumberOfStudents <<  " Student Names" << endl;
cin >> classroom.ListOfStudents;
cout << "Enter number of chairs" << endl;
cin >> classroom.NumberOfChairs;
cout << "Are there any Windows? (Y/N)" << endl;
cin >> classroom.Window;
cout << "Are there any Projectors? (Y/N)" << endl;
cin >> classroom.Projector;
cout << "Are there any Available? (Y/N)" << endl;
cin >> classroom.Available;

    return 0;
}
```

**Errors**

```
prog.cpp:10:5: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘classroom::NumberOfStudents’
 int NumberOfStudents;
     ^
prog.cpp:11:20: error: from this location
 int ListOfStudents[NumberOfStudents];
                    ^
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:28:18: error: ‘struct classroom’ has no member named ‘ListOfStudents’
 cin >> classroom.ListOfStudents;
                  ^
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to give the type and the instance different names to avoid confusion. E.g. `struct ClassRoom` and `classroom`. Having said that, you'd need to check the name look-up rules to see if the compiler is right in thinking `classroom` in main refers to the type.

Comment: As tristan said you should go for an array with const size or for some standard containers like vectors or lists

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't declare the array `int ListOfStudents[NumberOfStudents]` unless `NumberOfStudents` is of type `const int`.  If it is variable (ie. not `const`), then the compiler doesn't know how to allocate space for your array.  So just change `int NumberOfStudents;` to `const int NumberOfStudents;`.  However when you do this, your struct will also expect `NumberOfStudents` to be static, so you'll actually need to write `static const int NumberOfStudents;`.

At this point, you won't be able to `cin >> classroom.NumberOfStudents`, and things get pretty ugly.  I'm assuming this isn't what you want to do.

If you do want a variable-sized array, then the standard way of doing this is to use heap allocation.  In other words, you need to declare `ListOfStudents` to be a pointer to an integer array, which you will allocate during runtime.

That is, you want to change your struct as follows:

```
struct classroom {
int RoomNumber;
int NumberOfChairs;
int NumberOfStudents;
int* ListOfStudents;
string LectureName;
bool Window, Projector, Available;
}classroom;
```

Then inside your `main` function (or in fact wherever you like), you'll need to call `new` to allocate some space.  Like this:

```
classroom.ListOfStudents = new int[classroom.NumberOfStudents];
```

One last note: Doing this, you'll also need to change your `cin >> classroom.ListOfStudents;` to a loop that will read all the values into your array.  Like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < classroom.NumberOfStudents; i++) {
  cin >> classroom.ListOfStudents[i];
}
```

As suggested by the other answers, it would also be a good idea to change the name of your variable `classroom` so it doesn't match the name of the struct.  However it should still compile just fine (I tested it).  It's just a bit confusing.

Comment: Or just use std::vector

Comment: Use std::vector even if the array isn't supposed to change for each instance of the struct?

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't support VLA (variable length array) so you should not use  ListOfStudents[NumberOfStudents].  Use a const instead

edit:

```
prog.cpp:28:18: error: ‘struct classroom’ has no member named ‘ListOfStudents’
 cin >> classroom.ListOfStudents;
```

this error says that there is no operator>> matched for type &int. you may want to loop and print each element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, by creating a local variable in your function (since global variables aren't though recommended):

```
struct classroom {
    int RoomNumber;
    int NumberOfChairs;
    int NumberOfStudents;
    int ListOfStudents[NumberOfStudents];
    string LectureName;
    bool Window, Projector, Available;
};

int main(){
    classroom myClassRoom;

    cout << "Please enter your room number" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.RoomNumber;
    cout << "Enter the name of the Lecture" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.LectureName;
    cout << "Enter  number of students" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.NumberOfStudents;
    cout << "Enter " << myClassRoom.NumberOfStudents <<  " Student Names" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.ListOfStudents;
    cout << "Enter number of chairs" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.NumberOfChairs;
    cout << "Are there any Windows? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.Window;
    cout << "Are there any Projectors? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.Projector;
    cout << "Are there any Available? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.Available;

    return 0;
}
```

Or if you want the global variable, change the name of it for the compiler to make difference between the structure and the variable name, and then use it in your `main()` function with `myClassRoom`, instead of `classroom`:

```
struct classroom {
    int RoomNumber;
    int NumberOfChairs;
    int NumberOfStudents;
    int ListOfStudents[NumberOfStudents];
    string LectureName;
    bool Window, Projector, Available;
}myClassRoom;
```

**EDIT:** You have the set the length for the `ListOfStudents` to be a fixed number, for example

```
int ListOfStudents[512];
```

And then, this code compiles in my VS:

```
struct classroom {
    int RoomNumber;
    int NumberOfChairs;
        int NumberOfStudents;
    int ListOfStudents[200];
    string LectureName;
    bool Window, Projector, Available;
};

int main(){
    classroom myClassRoom;

    cout << "Please enter your room number" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.RoomNumber;
    cout << "Enter the name of the Lecture" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.LectureName;
    cout << "Enter  number of students" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.NumberOfStudents;
    cout << "Enter " << myClassRoom.NumberOfStudents <<  " Student Names" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < myClassRoom.NumberOfStudents; ++i)
    {
        cin >> myClassRoom.ListOfStudents[i];
    }
    cout << "Enter number of chairs" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.NumberOfChairs;
    cout << "Are there any Windows? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.Window;
    cout << "Are there any Projectors? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.Projector;
    cout << "Are there any Available? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> myClassRoom.Available;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is a variable which is global with name classroom

Comment: The code should compile without changing the instance name. The problem is the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable of the same name as a struct, change the "classroom" at the bottom of the struct to something else. Or make the Struct "Classroom".

```
struct Classroom {
    int RoomNumber;
    int NumberOfChairs;
    int NumberOfStudents;
    int ListOfStudents[NumberOfStudents];
    string LectureName;
    bool Window, Projector, Available;
}somethingelse;
```

You could also make a variable of type struct in main using:

```
classroom someClassroom;
```

Comment: This is not the issue. It isn't a good idea for the instance name to mask the class name, but the code should compile. The problem really is the VLA.